# Dynamic Text and/or images in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

first of all quite new with working with salesforce. I googled around, a bit, but haven't been able to find a solution to this.
So I have been looking at LWC's. Let's say I create a LWC with a specific image and text layout, and if I want to reuse that component, is it possible to dynamically change the text and the image of it via salesforce, rather than creating a new component having the same layout, but different text/images?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, and there's more than one way to do it. I would recommend going through these trailheads

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=Lightning%20Web%20Components

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a few ways to do this, depending on your goals. This is one of the core tenants of components, to be able to make reusable parts that can be used as templates for other component parts.

Generally speaking, the two main ways to do this are by slots and attributes.

## Slots

```
<template>
  <slot name="image">
    <img src="default.png" />
  </slot>
</template>
```

...

```
<template>
  <c-my-example-component>
    <img src="override.png" slot="image" />
  </c-my-example-component>
</template>
```

---

## Attributes

```
<template>
  <div>
    {myOutputText}
  </div>
</template>
```

...

```
<template>
  <c-my-example-component2 myOutputText="Hello World!">
  </c-my-example-component2>
</template>
```

---

You'll find all of this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc). I suggest reading it from front-to-back, it only takes a couple of hours, and most of the concepts are really simple. You can also create examples in the [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) without needing to deploy code in your org.